# Pycharm Refactor -> Rename removes type hint

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I am trying to rename a pytest fixture. But, when I do, the fixture's type hint gets removed.

Let's say I have the code:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def foo() -> str:
  return ""

def test_foo(foo: str):
  pass
```

If I do `Refactor -> Rename` to change "foo" to "baz", its type is removed from the test:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def baz() -> str:
  return ""

def test_foo(baz):
  pass
```

If a fixture is used in many places, this is annoying; I have to go through and restore the type hint.

How do I rename while preserving the type hint?

Comment: I confirm this happens. It looks like a bug to me. I'd suggest you file it at [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: Thank you for confirming. [Here's the bug on YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-58037/Refactor-Rename-remove-typehint-for-pytest-fixtures).

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug and is being tracked on JetBrains YouTrack [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44112/Renaming-a-pytest-fixture-deletes-typing-information).